# How can I embed a javascript in my AS3 (AIR) code?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, air

There is this website : https://www.windfinder.com/widget/configurator/meridien_noumea_airport that allow us to copy/paste their forecast script in order to embed it where we want.

Here's the script :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://www.windfinder.com/widget/forecast/js/meridien_noumea_airport?unit_wave=m&unit_rain=mm&unit_temperature=c&unit_wind=kts&columns=2&days=4&show_day=1">
    </script>
    <noscript>
    <a rel='nofollow' href='https://www.windfinder.com/forecast/meridien_noumea_airport?utm_source=forecast&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=homepageweather&utm_content=noscript-forecast'>
    Wind forecast for Nouméa Magenta Aéroport
    </a> provided by 
    <a rel='nofollow' 
    href='https://www.windfinder.com?utm_source=forecast&utm_medium=web&utm_campaign=homepageweather&utm_content=noscript-logo'>windfinder.com
    </a>
    </noscript>
```

I've got an AIR app (as3) and I'd like to embed and display this widget.

Is there a way to do so ?

What I did for now :

1-Copy/paste the javascript code into a .js file. 
2- Create, in the same folder, a .fla file with as3 code.

So how could I call the js file with AS3 (AIR app) ?

Thx

---

**EDIT**

If you have other idea how I can execute the script code given by the website into my AIR app, I'm completely open to new ideas !

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, JS code cannot be directly embedded into an AIR project like the way you have mentioned above.

The only possible solution that I can think of here is to use the `HTMLLoader` or `StageWebView` which is an inbuilt class in AIR which act's like a browser inside the AIR app.

Would recommend you read more about them here:

**HTMLLoader**

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html

**StageWebView**

- http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html

You may to have to create a local HTML file with your script embedded within it and then load that page within a Stage web view instance in your app.

Please note that you may run into various issues like layering your content above the stage web view etc, or to communicate between the JS and your AIR app.

Hope this helps to point you in the right direction. Cheers.